# Странное поведение hide()

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap

Метод `hide()` отрабатывает, но элементы через доли секунды элементы опять отображаются. В чем проблема?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#search").click(function(){

        var name=$("input").val();

        $(".users_data").each(function(){
            if ($(this).children(".nickname").text()!==name){
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });

    });    

});
```

Пробовал и через `.css({'display': 'none'})` и через `.addClass('hidden')` -- результат тот же. Использую Bootstrap3, может он опять возвращает видимость?

Comment: сюда бы [mcve], но меня несколько смущает, что вы перебирая потомков одного из `.user_data` скрываете их все, а не только проверяемый. Это полный код? или все таки, там кроме `hide`, где то еще и `show` есть?

Comment: Опечатка, там должно быть: $(this).hide(); Думаю, какая-то загвоздка в each(), потому что замена на $(this).remove(); приводит к аналогичному результату.

Comment: Ты всегда скрываешь всех `.users_data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> но через доли секунды элементы опять отображаются. В чем проблема? ... замена на `$(this).remove();` приводит к аналогичному результату.

`<telepathy>`
Кнопка с `id="search"` на Вашей странице имеет `type="submit"` - явно прописанный или по умолчанию - и находится внутри тэга `form`. Код Вашего обработчика отрабатывает и прячет нужный элемент, но процесс сабмита формы продолжается своим чередом. В результате, в браузер загружается новая страница, где все элементы опять видимые.
`</telepathy>`

Надо:

```
$("#search").click(function() {
  ...
  return false;
});
```

или

```
$("#search").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
});
```

или

```
<button id="search" type="button" ...</button>
```